# Effective Realization of GCD of middle binomials?

Tags: nt.number-theory, binomial-coefficients

So, it is well-known that 
$$ \gcd \left(\binom{m}{k}\mid 1\leq k\lt m \right) = e^{\Lambda(m)}$$
which can incidentally be sparsified for prime $p$
$$ \gcd \left(\binom{p^{r+1}}{1},\binom{p^{r+1}}{p^r}\right) = p $$
and composite $m$
$$ \gcd \left(m,\binom{m}{p^k} \mid p^k \| m\right) = 1 $$

While Understanding that it'll be tricky to get out something as intermittent as von-Mangoldt without putting in something fiddly (like, say, Möbius ...)

1. Are there clean/effective realizations of these $\gcd$s as particular integer combinations?

   1.1. in particular, is there one that, in some natural sense, treats the prime and composite cases the same?
2. Have you a favourite such?

---

For example, it is far from a proof or algorithm, but several small cases can be worked-out, with various tricks, from the fact that for $\omega$ a primitive 3rd root of unity, $1+\omega$ is a square root of $\omega$, e.g.:
$$ \omega^2 = (1+\omega)^4 = 1 + \binom{4}{1} \omega + \binom{4}{2} \omega^2 + \binom{4}{3} \omega^3 + \omega^4 $$
$$ 1 = \omega + \binom{4}{1} \omega^2 + \binom{4}{2} + \binom{4}{1} \omega + \omega^2 $$ 
$$ 2 = \binom{4}{2} - \binom{4}{1} $$
I anticipate, however, that these various tricks probably won't work for $\binom{25}{n}$.

Comment: This is related to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/167901

Comment: @JesseC.McKeown what is $\Lambda(m),\mbox{ }\|m$?

Comment: $\Lambda$ is the von-Mangoldt function; $ p^r \| m $ here means that $p^r | m $ and $p^{r+1} \not | m$

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in the following way (this construction is taken from the paper [Coefficient rings of formal groups](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=8523&option_lang=eng), it was also a part of the answer to the question [Is there a better proof of this fact in number theory/formal group theory?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167901/is-there-a-better-proof-of-this-fact-in-number-theory-formal-group-theory)).

If $n=p^k$ then $\binom{n}{p^{k-1}}\equiv p\pmod{p^2},$ so we can easely find $\lambda_{p^{k-1}}$ such that $\lambda_{p^{k-1}}\binom{p^k}{p^{k-1}}\equiv p\pmod {p^{k}}$. So for some $\lambda_{1}$
$$\lambda_{p^{k-1}}\binom{p^k}{p^{k-1}}+\lambda_{1}\binom{p^k}{1}=p.$$

Now let $n=p_1^{k_1}\ldots p_s^{k_s}$, where $s>1$. Then by [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem) $\mathrm{ord}_{p_i}\binom{n}{p_i^{k_i}}=0$ and $\mathrm{ord}_{p_j}\binom{n}{p_i^{k_i}}\ge k_j$ ($j\ne i$). Taking $\lambda_{p_i^{k_i}}\equiv \binom{n}{p_i^{k_i}}^{-1}\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$ we'll have

$$\lambda_{p_1^{k_1}}\binom{n}{p_1^{k_1}}+\ldots+\lambda_{p_s^{k_s}}\binom{n}{p_s^{k_s}}\equiv 1\pmod n.$$
So for some $\lambda_1$ 
$$\lambda_{p_1^{k_1}}\binom{n}{p_1^{k_1}}+\ldots+\lambda_{p_s^{k_s}}\binom{n}{p_s^{k_s}}+\lambda_{1}\binom{n}{1}=1.$$

Comment: Hmmm. I agree that this is a good recipe, and I agree that this contains more than "the relevant binomials have THIS gcd", in that most of "The Same" inverse coefficients get used for all composite cases... I do want to say I wasn't lacking for an algorithm to find solutions. Still, this IS already better than that!